# Cant download Roblox game

Tags: games

How do I install Roblox game on PC? When i try to install wine on terminal I get this message, E: Unable to locate package wine-stable"

Comment: Use `sudo apt install wine`

Comment: However, note that not all windows software are compatible with Wine

Comment: As packages are built for a specific release, and we don't know yours, our advice can only be *generic* and not tailored for your *unstated* OS & release.

Comment: Proposing to close the question, since the OP did not investigate nor delivered any data (Ubuntu version) we could work with. Therefore seconding @guiverc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)